# how to hide my encryption key in php

Tags: php, encryption

I have developed one application in PHP which uses encryption and decryption.
I have used mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt functions.

But i want to hide my encryption key somehow. so that other network users could not see it.
How can i do that ?

I try to save my key in an individual file and than make exe of that file. but when i execute it on my php page than it returns blank.

I tried -> `exec('key.exe',$key); print_r($key);`

can anyone help me that how can i hide my encryption key ?
is there any other way ?

,

Mausami

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the key from exactly?

Comment: If your app can get at the key, then someone breaking into the system can get at the key. All you can do is add more layers of obfuscation.

Comment: I want to hide it from all other users of client's network.

Comment: The php code is running on the server. So you just need to secure the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with `exec()` command.

We cant use `file_get_contents('key.exe')` because it cant give the original content.

I got the solution with this code

```
$str = exec('path\key.exe'); 
echo $str;
```

Thanks Alex Lunix, Marc B, CodeslnChaos, Daryl Gill, jogesh_p and prdatur for your help.

Comment: Sorry but this solution is the exact same way as with shell_exec, exec returns just the last line of the output from key.exe, shell_exec will return the hole return output. so shell_exec must worked as well if you didn't disabled the function within your php.ini. anyway, good to see that you have found a way.

Comment: yes prdatur. It is working with the same way with shell_exec also. Previously it was some issue on IIS server. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide your encryption key outside of your web directory, and use

```
$File = "/Path/To/File.ext";
$EncryptKey = file_get_contents($File);
print_r($EncryptKey);
```

Hide it outside your web directory so only the script can access it; or an administrator with full system access.

Comment: hi Daryl Gill, It not finding the file and giving me error message that Warning: file_get_contents(config/key.ext) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @Mausami it means the given function `file_get_content()` not able to get the file, make sure about the path of the file. Also make sure about the read permission on the server..

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. i run the code with the file key.exe but as it is exe file its giving output in more than a page like these type of characters :  MZ���Έ@Ί΄ Ν!ΈLΝ!This program cannot be run in DOS mode. $RΟq(®{®{®{m²{5®{�{®{•²{®{ι�{®{‘²{9®{@±{ ®{®{ ®{t±{®{®{π―{ώ±{®{ώ±{"―{®¨{®{ώ±{®{Rich®{PELσΉςDΰΐ ½Π@°PΊ²_\• PΠ .text¬±ΐ `.rdataJΠPΠ@@.datadz ΐ @ΐ.rsrcP ΰ@@U‹μjj�u�u�u�u�uθƒΔ]ΓU‹μ�μ¬�EΜS‰Eπ�Eΰ‰EΔ�Eτ‰EΤ‹E 3ΫV+ΓW‰]ΐ�]μ‰]δtqHtEH…�Eμ‹uP�EΌP�EΈP�EόP�EθP�EPht QV�uθϊΒ ‹MΌƒΔ$‰

Comment: how can i get the key ? i want to use that key for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the executeable file "key.exe" you could use

```
$output = shell_exec('key.exe');
```

which stores the output of the key.exe within the $output variable.
You can also try to create a temp file with:

```
exec('key.exe > C:/output'); // Store output data from key.exe to c:/output
$output = file_get_contents('C:/output'); // read the output file
unlink('C:/output');  // Delete the output file after reading
```

But you can also manually create your encryption key and save it to a file c:/mykey and then use just the

```
file_get_contents('c:/mykey');
```

Pathes are for windows because key.exe sounds like you have a windows machine, if not use **/tmp/** instead if **c:**

Comment: Thanks prdatur for your answer but none of them is working. shell_exec('key.exe') returns blank and exec also returns blank array.

Comment: is there any other way than executable files to hide the key ? if there is any other better way than i can use that also.